# 3D points in geoalchemy2

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy2

I'm having difficulty with (I think) the ORM for geoalchemy2.  My model is defined as follows:

```
class Location(Model):
    point = Column(Geometry('POINT', dimension=3, srid=4326))
```

I later insert as follows:

```
location = Location(point=WKTElement('POINT(65.567 32.95 1156.7)', 4326))
session.add(location)
session.commit()
```

This gives the following error:

```
Geometry has Z dimension but column does not.
```

Comment: I know this is a long time ago, but did you ever find a solution?

Comment: The 3D support is undocumented but it's there, see https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2/issues/157 and https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2/issues/67

Comment: changing `POINT` into `POINTZ` seems to solve the issue; Although I experience that this wont work for `LINESTRINGZ`